# MySQL select all where date (stored in varchar type)

Tags: php, mysql, date, select, varchar

I have made a mistake when I originally designed my DB and I have an "appointments" table with ID, DATE, TIME but the type of DATE field is VARCHAR and I'm saving with this format: 29/08/2015

Now I would like to run a query that selects all appointments, 2 days from TODAY.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Sidenote: if you're not too far into your project, you can always alter your table.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm way too far! :(

Comment: @Andr That is highly unlikely!

Comment: Cast the **DATE** field from your query to Datetime while quering.

Answer (score 2):

You should fix the column definition in the table and in the meanwhile to retrieve the data you need to use `str_to_date` function

```
select * from table_name
where str_to_date(DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') = date_add(now(),interval 2 day)
```

The varchar dates are not real date and will create more issues for different section, to fix the table column you can follow the steps as

step 1:

```
alter table table_name add column new_date date ;
```

step 2:

```
update table_name set new_date = str_to_date(DATE,'%d/%m/%Y');
```

step3 :

```
alter table_name drop column DATE ;
alter table_name change new_date DATE date
```

Comment: *"You should fix the column definition in the table"* - Indeed. However, OP responded to my comment to them and are apparently too far in their project. This looks promising though.

Comment: Yes i cannot alter the field type now.. we have lots of data and we will mess the system

Comment: Yes that was a recommendation and you may or may not follow but to make life simple thats the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`date();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$twoDaysFromNow = date('d/m/y', time() + 172800); // Adds exactly two days (172,800 seconds) to the current day, and returns it in given format.

$sql = "SELECT FROM `appointments` WHERE `date` = '{$twoDaysFromNow}'"; // Execute query with new date.
```

Comment: you have a misplaced tick after `{$twoDaysFromNow}'` that belong in / after `appointments`

Comment: ah, there we go and you're welcome. Let's see what the OP says now ;-)

Comment: I feel like it's good practice to add them. Seems to cause more headaches than it [doesn't] solves, however. ;)

Comment: How can i modify this to become a between dates? I mean between TODAY and "$twoDaysFromNow" ?

Comment: Unfortunately that becomes a little more tricky. You need to build an array of all possible dates. `WHERE date IN ("01/01/1970", "02/01/1970", ...);`. That's one of the limitations of having it as a string datatype.

Comment: @Andr *"How can i modify this to become a between dates?"* - that's a "another" question altogether. You should mark one of the answers that may have solved your original question and not add to it "after the fact".